# ApplicationContext не запускает lifecycle бины

Tags: java, spring

public static void main:

```
ConfigurableApplicationContext ctx = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("conf.xml");
ctx.start()
```

---

В conf.xml:

```
<bean id="lifeBean" class="LifeBean"/>
```

В LifeBean.java

```
public class LifeBean implements Lifecycle {
  private boolean isRunning=true;
  @Override
  public void start() {
    System.out.println("Start");
  }
  @Override
  public void stop() {
    System.out.println("Stop");
  }
  @Override
  public void isRunning() {
    return isRunning;
  }
}
```

---

В вывод идет

```
INFO: Starting beans in phase 0.
```

Но нет вывода методов start и stop.

Как это должно работать? Хотелось бы увидеть пример, в котором был бы вывод методов start и stop в консоль, если это конечно возможно, а то я возможно не так понимаю принцип использования Lifecycle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Метод `start` не вызывается, т.к. `isRunning` возвращает всегда `true` (что логично - зачем запускать бин, если он и так запущен?). Исправить это можно, инициализировав `isRunning` со значением `false` и изменяя её значение в методах `start` и `stop`.

Метод `stop` не вызывается, в свою очередь, из-за отсутствия вызова метода `stop` контекста. Исправить это можно, вызвав `stop` контекста, либо используя try-with-resources.